# Date/Time comparison in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, time, comparison

I have these dates and times:

```
schedule.day_start    # => 2014-09-27 15:30:00 UTC
date_now = Time.now   # => 2014-09-27 15:11:14 +0200
date_now + 60.minutes # => 2014-09-27 16:11:14 +0200
```

I am trying to detect all schedules that start 60 minutes or less before `day_start`. With the following code, I get as a response `"NO"` instead of `"YES"`.

```
if schedule.day_start < (Time.now + 60.minutes)
  "YES"
else
  "NO"
end
```

Why is `2014-09-27 15:30:00 UTC` bigger than `2014-09-27 16:11:14 +0200`?

Answer (score 14):

Work them dates as UTC, so you will avoid time zone problems

```
if schedule.day_start.utc < (Time.now + 60.minutes).utc
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks Benjamin for your message. I tried it, but `Time.now.utc` shows me `2014-09-27 14:10:14 UTC`, but the current time is `2014-09-27 16:10:14 UTC`. How to compare these two dates then? (`schedule.day_start` shows the "correct" date - not `-2 hours`)

Comment: In which context do you get `Time.now`? Because if for example it is assigned to a constant or a global variable it could have record the time when you started your server. Also check if you correctly set-up your `config.time_zone`, and off course if your system is on the right time with `ntpdate`

Answer (score 2):

Because

```
2014-09-27 16:11:14 +0200
```

is simultaneous to

```
2014-09-27 14:11:14 UTC
```

which comes before

```
2014-09-27 15:30:00 UTC
```

With `Time` objects, "follows" translates to "greater".

Comment: Thank you Sawa for your message. But could you explain me, please, what do you mean by `With Time objects, "follows" translates to "greater".`?

Comment: If time `A` comes after (i.e. **follows**) time `B` on the temporal scale, then code `A > B` in Ruby would be `true` (i.e., `A` is **greater** than `B`).

Answer (score 0):

Anywhere, if time A comes after time B, then A is considered to be greater than B. The same is in your case.

---

> schedule.day_start    # => 2014-09-27 15:30:00 UTC
>
> date_now + 60.minutes # => 2014-09-27 16:11:14 +0200 which is 2014-09-27 14:11:14 UTC.

Here, you can clearly see that, Time.now + 60.minutes is a *timestamp* before schedule.day_start. Thus, schedule.day_start is greater than Time.now + 60.minutes, that's why your **"if"** case doesn't hold true and hence **NO** is printed.

Answer (score 0):

Rememeber your result is *false* because the GMT, to resolve this and compare the only datetime without GMT using UTC, try this:

```
minutes = 60.minutes 
t1 = Time.at(schedule.day_start.utc).to_datetime
t2 = Time.at((Time.now + minutes).utc).to_datetime

if t1 < t2
  "YES"
else
  "NO"
end
```